# How does Google App Engine manage sessions inside cluster?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, paas, nosql

A cluster contains several nodes, and if one of current node is down, other nodes can retrieve current user session.

I was thinking about how to do the same thing myself (session replication) if I want to create my own high availaible Paas (Cloud).

May I use a key/value database (NoSQL) in order to store/retrieve sessions ? Or something similar.

How does Google for its Google App Engine ? Does Google use a [Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) in order to rewrite [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) API (Java) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in appengine, the session is simply kept in its datastore. you can do the same or improve it by adding a caching layer with memcache.